# Access next index object's value within a loop - Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I wanted to check for a condition if a particular property of an object is same as the very next object's property in an array-of-objects, iterated through a `v-for` loop.

Sample JSON object:

```
[
  { Date: '21-July-2017', ...},
  { Date: '21-July-2017', ...},
  { Date: '25-July-2017', ...},
  ...
]
```

The requirement is to check if each consecutive `Date` value is same, so that we will hide the `Date` header in the UI.

```
<div v-for="(everyDay, dayIndex) in eachPost.values" v-bind:key="dayIndex">
  <div v-if="everyDay['Date'] !== eachPost.values[dayIndex+1].Date">
     THIS DOESN'T WORK
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there an alternative to accomplish this req?

Comment: Better way would be to use a computed property and filter them as unique, would keep your view cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is when you get to your last item in the array your `dayIndex+1` object does not exist. It is `undefined`. What you need to do is in your template determine if your object is defined and go from there.

```
  <div v-for="(everyDay, dayIndex) in eachPost.values" v-bind:key="dayIndex">
   <template v-if="eachPost.values[dayIndex+1]">
      <div v-if="everyDay['Date'] !== eachPost.values[dayIndex+1].Date">
         THIS WORKS
      </div>
  </template>

 </div>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/434143/) of my working example